# Bubble sort with files

Tags: c#, bubble-sort

Ok, please excuse my very crude code, but this project was made in haste (and slight irritation). I am to sort 20 numbers between 1-40 inclusive, but i cannot use any data containers (arrays, etc) and I also cannot use a variable for each number. I came up with the idea to use 20 files as individual array pieces. I am trying to implement the bubble sort (hasty pick) to sort the data in the files. Problem is, I don't have much experience yet writing to files, so its becoming a very, very large headache.

```
for (int i = 0; i <20; i++) // assign smallest
{
   for (int j = 1; j <= 19; j++ ) // find the smallest
   {

      filename = "" + j.ToString() + ".txt";          // _.txt assigned to filename
      file = File.OpenText("" + filename);            //file assigned path of _.txt
      a = Int32.Parse(file.ReadLine());               //pull number from file 1, assign to a
      file.Close();
      filename1 = "" + (j + 1).ToString() + ".txt";   // _+1.text assigned to filename1
      file1 = File.OpenText( filename1);              //   file1 assigned path of _+1.txt
      b = Int32.Parse(file1.ReadLine());              // pull number from file 2, assign to b

      file1.Close();


      if (a > b) //bubble sort
      {
          temp = a;  // assign temp to a

          Sorting = File.CreateText( filename);
          Sorting.Write(b);

          Sorting = File.CreateText( filename1);
          Sorting.Write(temp);

          Sorting.Close();

      }
   }
}
```

Theres a logic error here thats throwing me off, at the end it says "cannot open 2.txt" after the outer for loop has ran once. It tells me this even though I'm sure to close the file streams for each iteration. Any insight will be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Is this a homework question? It seems like an add restriction that you couldn't even use an array..

Comment: Don't do this with a bubble sort. Do it with a merge sort. It's hard to imagine that they said you can't keep the items in memory. Perhaps they want you to use a linked list?

Comment: Nope, can't use an array or any other sort of array-like structures. It is a HW assignment, but this restriction seems a bit silly. Ill look into the merge sort right now

Comment: A linked list is not an array-like structure.